# How can I add median points to every violin in a multiple violin plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I am making grouped violin plots of my own dataset using ggplot2. The dataset contains 350 observations (7 scenarios in 5 locations and every situation has 10 replicates) of 3 variables and part of it looks like this:

Part of my dataset:
[image]

The codes I used are here:

```
DF = read.csv("C:\\Users\\lqy\\Desktop\\Pilot_data.csv", na.strings = "---", header = TRUE)
DF = data.frame(DF)

DF$Scenarios = as.integer(DF$Scenarios)
    
figure = ggplot(DF, aes(x = Location, y = Recovery, fill = Scenarios)) +
  geom_violin() + 
  stat_summary(fun="median",geom="point") +
  labs(x="Locations", y="Days to 90% recovery") +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 10)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 10)) +
  theme(legend.position = "right")
figure
```

From these codes I have a figure that looks like this:

[image]

I am quite happy with this figure but the median points I added seem to be clustered in the middle of the plot, instead of in each violins. I'm guessing this is because they are supposed to align right above the point on the x-axis. But is there a way to put the median points in each corresponding violin in this kind of plot?

Many thanks for answering this question for me!

ADDITION: the dataset is here
(acquired by the code `dput(DF[sample(nrow(DF),45),])`)

```
structure(list(Scenarios = c(8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 
10L, 3L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 10L, 4L, 8L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 
10L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 10L), Location = c("Total_Catchment", 
"Sec_51", "Sec_53", "Total_Catchment", "Sec_55", "Sec_55", "Sec_51", 
"Sec_51", "Sec_54", "Total_Catchment", "Sec_55", "Sec_55", "Sec_54", 
"Sec_53", "Sec_51", "Sec_55", "Sec_53", "Sec_55", "Sec_54", "Total_Catchment", 
"Sec_51", "Sec_53", "Sec_55", "Total_Catchment", "Sec_54", "Total_Catchment", 
"Sec_53", "Sec_53", "Sec_51", "Sec_54", "Sec_53", "Sec_51", "Sec_53", 
"Sec_54", "Sec_54", "Sec_55", "Sec_55", "Sec_54", "Sec_51", "Sec_51", 
"Sec_51", "Total_Catchment", "Sec_51", "Sec_55", "Sec_53"), Recovery = c(316.5, 
839.5, 179.5, 277.5, 923.5, 664.5, 494.5, 639.5, 273.5, 327.5, 
830.5, 714.5, 357.5, 300.5, 504.5, 752.5, 265.5, 535.5, 208.5, 
303.5, 564.5, 339.5, 766.5, 396.5, 273.5, 271.5, 185.5, 370.5, 
825.5, 191.5, 186.5, 582.5, 364.5, 326.5, 332.5, 901.5, 706.5, 
187.5, 577.5, 680.5, 506.5, 301.5, 559.5, 713.5, 324.5)), row.names = c(20L, 
121L, 163L, 37L, 329L, 348L, 103L, 112L, 273L, 52L, 322L, 309L, 
240L, 187L, 76L, 338L, 155L, 339L, 253L, 69L, 133L, 158L, 342L, 
2L, 235L, 45L, 146L, 161L, 106L, 239L, 189L, 117L, 157L, 265L, 
258L, 299L, 321L, 215L, 98L, 127L, 132L, 27L, 111L, 283L, 203L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please `dput(DF)` and paste the output in your question in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I tried the command dput(DF) but the data is too long to be copied here. Is there another way to copy my dataset here? Sorry I'm super new to R. @Duck

Comment: Try `dput(DF[sample(nrow(DF),45),])` and paste the output in your question!

Comment: I have copied the output in my question!

Answer (score 4):

The solution will probably involve adding a dodge position to the summary layer. Example with dummy data below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  Locations = rep(c("Sec_51", "Sec_53"), each = 1000),
  Recovery = rnorm(2000),
  Scenarios = rep(rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 200), 2)
)

ggplot(df, aes(Locations, Recovery,
               group = interaction(Locations, Scenarios))) +
  geom_violin(aes(fill = Scenarios)) +
  stat_summary(fun = median, geom = "point",
               position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering my question. I have tried your code and the median points are in the violins! But I don't know why my scenarios are no longer integers. They were 1X,2X,3X,...,10X benchmark scenarios so the scenarios should be integers. Still trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

How to do this using Vlnplot function for the following code:

```
seurat_01 <- readRDS("/home/mitralab/data2/20210204-integrated_seurat_T1exp_T10exp_Tolexp_0.2.Rds")
```

### Cluster gene expression map 0.2 using raw count

```
library(patchwork)
library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(Seurat)
gene_list <- c("NDUFV1","NDUFV2","NDUFS1","NDUFS2","NDUFS3","NDUFS8","NDUFS7",
               "MT-ND1","MT-ND2","MT-ND3","MT-ND4","MT-ND4L","MT-ND5","MT-ND6")

data <- seurat_01
DefaultAssay(data) <- "RNA"
plot_list <- list()
for (i in gene_list) {
  plot_list[[i]] <- FeaturePlot(data, features = i, split.by = "sample", cols = c("grey","blue"))
}
vplot_list <- list()
data$clusternum <- Idents(data)
for (i in gene_list) {
  vplot_list[[i]] <- VlnPlot(data, features = i, split.by = "sample", group.by = "clusternum",
    pt.size = 0, combine = FALSE) + stat_summary(fun = median, geom = 'point', size = 2, color = 'black')
    + 
   scale_y_continuous('Expression Level') + 
   scale_x_discrete("Identity")
}
for (i in gene_list) {
  ggsave(paste0("/home/mitralab/featureplot/","map_", i, "_0.2_raw.pdf"),plot = plot_list[[i]], width = 11, height = 8.5)
  pdf(paste0("/home/mitralab/vlnplot/","vin_", i, "_0.2_raw.pdf"), width = 11, height = 8.5)
   print(vplot_list[[i]])
  dev.off()
}
```